# How to print sample records from tf.dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensorflow dataset called imdb. How can I print top 5 records of this dataset (including header)? I am looking for something similar to `dataframe.head()` in pandas. Some of the datasets can have images as well.

```
   import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
   imdb, info = tfds.load("imdb_reviews", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

The code `print(type(imdb))` returns `<class 'dict'>`. I understand `tfds.show_examples` supports only images. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have eager execution enabled, this will show the first five examples:

```
for x in imdb['train'].take(5):
    print(x)
```